# Can't use Python on Zeppelin notebooks

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata, aws-glue, apache-zeppelin

I just installed Zeppelin so I can start does some testing with spark and AWS Glue. I selected python as my interpreter. I started off by writing the following command in the notebook to test it

`%python print ("Hello World")`

However when I try that I get the following error:

> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open PythonInterpreter
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:844)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:752)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open PythonInterpreter
> at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.open(PythonInterpreter.java:123)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
> 8 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch python process.
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:205)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140)
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:647)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:279)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:336)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
> 1 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:319)
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:249)
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1111)
> 8 more
>
> at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.createGatewayServerAndStartScript(PythonInterpreter.java:170)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.open(PythonInterpreter.java:120)
> 9 more

I'm using a MacBook Pro with a Apple M1 chip.  I've confirmed python works on my terminal as well.
Is there anything I'm missing that is preventing me from using python on Zeppelin?

I checked my .zshrc configuration to the following to see if that will work:

alias python=/usr/bin/python3

export SPARK_HOME=/Users//Documents/Projects/spark/spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2

I also tried logging off my company's VPN and restarting the terminal.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out.  I went to the interpreter section of Zeppelin and changed the zeppelin.python configuration to the path that I have python installed.

Comment: Either answer your own question and accept the answer or delete this question

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @itprorh66, I'm still getting familiar with stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just figured it out. I went to the interpreter section of Zeppelin and changed the zeppelin.python configuration to the path that I have python installed.